# Bind type variable to element type of collection

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

How does one bind a polymorphic type variable to the parameter of a unary type constructor in Scala?

```
def f[CollectionOfE] = new Blah[...]
{
  def g(a: E) = 
  { ... } 
}

...

val x = f[Set[Int]]  // want E above to bind to Int
```

Within the definition of *g* i wish to be able to refer to the parameter type of the collection on which *f* has been instantiated.

I've tried:

```
def f[C[E]] = new Blah[...] ...
```

but the scope of E seems to be local to the `[` ... `]`, if that makes any sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, you might want something like this:

```
def f[E, C[_]] = new Blah[...] {
  def g(e: E) = ???
}

...

f[Int, Set]
```

Basically, if you want to refer to a type later, you need to put it as a separate type parameter. You might also want to limit type of `C[_]` to some collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you define `E` a separate parameter. E.g.

```
def f[E, C <: util.Collection[E]] = new Blah  {
   def g(a: E) = ...
}

val x = f[Int, Set[Int]].g(1)  // compiles

val y = f[Int, Set[Int]].g("string")  // doesn't compile
```

**Edit**
You can make it slightly more concise by calling the function with underscore:

```
f[Int, Set[_]].g(1)
```